# Are linear problems on rational numbers decidable in Z3?

Tags: haskell, z3, smt, decidable, sbv

I'm working with linear problems on rationals in **Z3**. To use **Z3** I take **SBV**.

An example of a problem I pose is:

```hs
import Data.SBV

solution1 = do
  x <- sRational "x"
  w <- sRational "w"
  constrain $ x.< w
  constrain $ x + 2*w .>=0 .|| x .== 1
```

My question is:

Are these kinds of problems decidable?
I couldn't find a list of decidable theories or a way to tell if a theory is decidable.
The closest I found is [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv-8.17/docs/Data-SBV.html#g:12). The theory about the real ones is decidable, but is it the same for rational numbers? Intuition tells me that it is, but I have not found the information that allows me to assure it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SBV models rationals using the standard "two integers" idea; that is, it represents the numerator and the denominator separately as integers. This means that if you add two symbolic rationals, you'll have a non-linear term over the integers. So, in theory, the problem will be in the semi-decidable fragment. That is, even if you restrict your multiplications to concrete scalars, addition of symbolic rationals will give rise to non-linear terms over integers.

Having said that, I had good luck using rationals; where z3 was able to decide most problems of interest without much difficulty. If it proves to be an issue, you should switch to `SReal` type (i.e., algebraic reals), for which z3 has a decision procedure. But of course, the models you get can now include algebraic reals, such as square-root-of-2, etc. (i.e., the roots of any polynomial with integer coefficients.)

*Side note* If your problem allows for delta-sat (i.e., satisfiability with perturbations), you should look into dReal (http://dreal.github.io), which SBV also supports as a backend solver. But perhaps that's not what you had in mind.

### Theoretical note

Strictly speaking, linear arithmetic over rationals is decidable; see Section 3 of https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/james.worrell/lecture15-2015.pdf for a proof. However, SMT solvers do *not* support rationals out-of-the-box; and SBV (as I mentioned above), uses two symbolic integers to represent rationals. So, adding two rationals will give rise to multiplication of two symbolic integers, taking you out of the decidable fragment. Of course, in practice, the solvers are quite adept at coming up with solutions even in the presence of non-linear terms; it's just that you're not always guaranteed. So, a more strict answer to your question is while linear arithmetic over rationals is decidable, the translation used by SBV puts the problem into the non-linear integer arithmetic domain, and hence decidability is not guaranteed. In any case, SMTLib does not come with a theory of rationals, so you're kind of out-of-luck when it comes to first class support for them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a rational solution will exist iff an *integer* solution exists to a suitably scaled collection of constraints. For example, `x=1/2(=5/10), w=3/5(=6/10)` is a solution to your example problem. Scaling your problem by 10, we have the equivalent constraint set:

```
10*x < 10*w
(10*x + 20*w >= 0) || (10*x == 10)
```

Writing `x'=10*x` and `w'=10*w`, this means that `x'=5, w'=6` is an integer solution to:

```
x' < w'
(x' + w' >= 0) || (x' == 10)
```

Presburger famously showed that first-order logic plus integers and addition is decidable. (Multiplication by a constant is also allowed, since it can be expanded to an addition -- e.g. 3*x is x+x+x.)

I guess the only trick left is to show that it's possible to choose what scaling to use without having solved the problem yet. Nothing obvious occurs to me off the top of my head, but it seems reasonable that this should be doable. For example, perhaps if you take the product of all the nonzero numerators and denominators in your constraint set, you can show that the set of rationals with that product as their denominator is indistinguishable from the full set of rationals. (If so, you could look through the proof to see if it still works with a smaller denominator.)

I'm not a z3 expert, so I can't talk about how this translates to whether that tool specifically is suitable, but it seems likely to me that it is possible to create a suitable tool.

Comment: Linear arithmetic over rationals is decidable, see section 3 of https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/james.worrell/lecture15-2015.pdf. However, the question here is a little different: Does z3 (as used by SBV in particular) have a decision procedure for them? I believe the answer to that is no; since it goes through integer arithmetic which can have non-linear terms arising from addition.